# Listening to the events that are happening in a page?

Tags: html, events

I'm trying to recognize the events that are happening in a page. For example, the page is loaded is one event then the user clicks a link it is another event or open a dropdown box and so on, so here I'm looking for all these events? any idea on how I can monitor the events that are happening in a html page?

Answer (score 1):

JQuery and Prototype have excellent cross-browser solutions for that.

JQ click example:

```
$('#foo').bind('click', function() {
  alert('User clicked on "foo."');
});
```

JQ DOM-ready example (page has loaded):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#foo').bind('click', function(event) {
    alert('The mouse cursor is at ('
      + event.pageX + ', ' + event.pageY + ')');
  });
});
```

Comment: @Ehsan does not know what the event, and you have to offer Jquery.

Comment: Yes, he wants to capture events and using a library is the easiest way imo.

Comment: @Jonathan What I'm looking in here is that I don't know what kind events can happen in a page I want to have a listener that tracks what events are happening in a page or that is to say, it can give me some logs of what events are happening in a page

Answer (score 0):

You can read about events here:

Events: http://w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp

Using: http://www.w3.org/wiki/Handling_events_with_JavaScript